# Session interchange issue in JSP

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

In my application **if two people are trying to login at the same time**, their sessions are getting interchanged. Or one will get **others session**. I am **using JSP and servlets**.
The piece of **code** for creating the session as follows(**in servlets**)

```
session.setAttribute("userid", new Long(userid));
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

If someone came across the same situation and solved this please help me fix this.

Comment: Please post some code related to session in your app.

Comment: Are you using 2 tabs on the same browser window and assuming that these are 2 sessions. try opening the page in 2 different browsers and then check.

Answer (score 0):

The 'userid' variable must be unique, so log its value to verify this. Also, there's more to session management than just this setting!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same browser to log in as different user? If its true, then it might be that you are not invalidating previous session in the log in screen. So let's say you logged in with user A and session object was created. Then you logged in with user B but session was not invalidated and you are adding parameters to the same session object as user A.